# Ionic/cordova Screen orientation not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've been developing an ionic app and it requires all but one screen to be locked in portrait mode. So I added the screen orienation plugin via

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

Then I added the supposedly simple line of code

`window.screen.lockOrientation('portrait');` //does not work

tried this aswell
`screen.lockOrientation('portrait');` //does not work

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
});
```

with **$ionicPlatform dependency** included //does not work

Seems pretty straight forward but nothing is working

Any help would be greatly appreciated..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reliably lock the orientation of the screen in the config files of your cordova project. Just use

```
 <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape" />
```

If you want to be more flexible and change it dependant to the current view. Go in the config files and add an orientation : 'portrait' attribute to the respective views. Afterwards simply declare:

```
 if(toState.orientation == 'portrait') {
 screen.lockOrientation('portrait');
 }
```

If that still doesn't work, try an implementation with another plugin. This seems to be a fair altervative with a slightly different approach: 
https://github.com/Adlotto/cordova-plugin-recheck-screen-orientation

Comment: I really like your second option...but could you explain it a bit further. How do I create an attribute an apply it in the .config file...I'm a complete noob